# How can know if the end of line in C

Tags: c

If I do :

```
int main(){
    const int LENGTH_LINE = 100;
    char line[LENGTH_LINE];
    int len;
    FILE* fp = fopen(file.txt,"r");

    fgets(line,LENGTH_LINE,fp);
    len = strlen(line);
    if(line[len-1] == '\n')
       printf("I've a line");

    //This work if the line have \n , but if the end line of the text dont have \n how can do it?


}
```

I need to know if I take a whole line with `fgets` because I got a delimiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets

```
Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in str. 
Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.
```

So, once fgets returns, there are 3 possibilities

1. LENGTH_LINE was reached
2. We got a newline
3. EOF was reached.

I'm assuming you have a line in cases 2 and 3.

In this case the detection condition is :

```
line[len-1] == '\n' || feof(fp)
```

Comment: I dont know why if i have : line1\n , my line have the first time :line1 , the second time: trash , why?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the newline character:

```
size_t len = 0;

// ... your code using fgets

len = strlen(line);
if ((len > 0) && (line[len - 1] == '\n'))
    // your input contains the newline
```

After the `fgets` call, your line may not have a newline at the end if:

- The character limit was reached before a newline was scanned - in your case this is `LENGTH_LINE`.
- The end-of-file (`EOF`) was reached before a newline.
- There was a read error, but in case of an error consider the contents of `line` unusable.

You should be looking at the return value from `fgets` so that you'll be able to handle the `EOF`: `fgets` returns `NULL` upon end-of-file or a read error. You can use `feof` to check for the end-of-file.

If you check `feof`, and know that you're at the end of your input with no `fgets` errors, then even without a newline character on the final line you'll know that you've read the entire line.

If for some reason you must have a newline character terminating each `line`, you can add it yourself:

```
// you've checked for EOF and know this is your final line:
len = strlen(line);
if (line[len-1] == '\n')
    printf("I've a line");
else if ((len + 1) < LENGTH_LINE)
{
    line[len] = '\n';
    line[len + 1] = '\0';
}
else
    // no room in your line buffer for an add'l character
```

Comment: That depends on your needs. Presumably you're looping through a file using `fgets` to get each line. If you capture the return value from `fgets` you'll know when you're at the end of the file, and using the above code you'll know if that last line ended with `'\n'` or not. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question: if so then please add more detail to the question.

Comment: the final line dont have '\n' , then line[len-1] != '\n' ... i dont know how to explain more , if i got : line1\n line2    then the line2 dont have '\n' but is the end of line and text...

Comment: if the final line has no `'\n'` then you can add one yourself, if there's room in your `line` string.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
while(fgets(line,LENGTH_LINE,fp)!=EOF)
  // your code here
```

Comment: you are comparing `char*` with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use fgetc instead? That way you can just keep scanning until you get to the end of the line so you don't have to check if you have it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[100]; 
    int ch, i = 0;

    FILE* fp = fopen(file.txt,"r");
    while(ch != '\n' || ch != '\r' || ch != EOF)  //or ch != delimiter
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        line[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\n';
    line[i+1] = 0x00;
    return 0;
}
```

In that example I just look for a new line, return, or EOF character but you can really make it look for anything you like (e.g. your delimiter). So if your delimiter was `q` you would just do

`while(ch != 'q')...`